# MySQL Trigger Sum on Update

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to get the cell `Points_Per_Game` to calculate using a trigger in MySQL, not sure what i'm missing.

```
Points_Per_Game = Total_Points / Games Played, 


DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Point_Per_Game 
AFTER UPDATE ON Players 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
UPDATE Players SET Points_Per_Game = Total_Points / Games_Played;  
END;$$
DELIMITER;
```

Players Table:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
| Name       | Games_Played | Total_Points | Points_Per_Game |
+------------+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
| David      |            0 |            0 |            NULL |
| John       |            6 |            7 |            NULL |
```

The `Games_Played` and `Total_Points` columns are updated weekly via a bash script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a *before* update trigger and you need to refer to the data in the row:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Point_Per_Game 
BEFORE UPDATE ON Players 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    SET new.Points_Per_Game = (CASE WHEN new.Games_Played > 0 THEN new.Total_Points / new.Games_Played ELSE 0 END);  
END;$$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: It went in correctly, thanks. My issue now is that when I Update Games_Played and Total_Points I get this error: `Can't update table 'Players' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

Comment: @denski . . . You should modify your question (or ask another) showing the code that does the update and any other triggers on the table.

Comment: This worked, I had two issues. 1) I had two triggers setup with the same trigger. 2) I'd set DECIMAL (3,3) so it wouldn't allow values that updated to greater than 0.